# What exactly is the RAM program runtime?

Tags: complexity, circuit, oblivious-ram

In my previous understanding, if a RAM program requires $T$ read/write operations to memory during its execution, then the runtime of this RAM program is $T$. However, as I have read some literature, I have realized that my understanding may not be correct.

For instance, there is a [paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/601.pdf) mentioning a $T$-time RAM program that can be transformed into a circuit of size $O(T^3 \log T)$. This is a result from complexity theory. However, if $T$ only represents the number of memory read/write operations, then this result is evidently incorrect because the size of the circuit when not performing read/write operations may be very large.

Therefore, what exactly $T$ represents? Thank you, everyone.

Comment: [This](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/957.pdf#page=14) uses "T-time RAM program". By my reading of it and [one of it's references](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/580.pdf#page=47), they both use "T-time" to mean time (a fixed) ___polynomial___ in T (for the side doing the bulk of the computation), not ___proportional___ to T. I don't make this an answer because the paper mentioned in the second paragraph remains unknown, and it may use different definitions.